# Getting used to Wired Reflexes

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, equipment

I am just trying to imagine having extremely boosted Reflexes. There is two ways to go about them that I can think of: (I hope the english version "wired reflexes" is the right translation)

**a)** Keep the wired reflexes active at all time, which would give you problems with beeing pretty fast and having very high reflexes in your normal day life, but you would eventually get used to those extreme reflexes you now have. I imagine someone knocking over stuff on a table while he is eating, accidentally hitting his friends when just turning to them on the couch, stuff like that. You do have really fast reflexes and would probably need to get used to your muscles/reflexes work so fast, right?

**b)** Just turn the reflexes on when you need them. Would be a bit awkward for you every time you activate them, but at least you could live your normal day life normally. I guess if you activated it a bit before a run or something, you could get used to them and at least do pretty well with them on the run?

So, basically, my question is: **How long would it take for someone to get used to his high reflexes in both cases? (a and b)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reflex adjustment you pay for typically includes mental acceleration.  This doesn't just boost your Reaction, it gives you more IP.  Hitting someone on accident is not really a reasonable problem, nor is spilling food.  Constantly interrupting people because they're going to slow, being frustrated at how slow one's one body moves, taking 'shortcuts' that shave seconds off of routine tasks like moving a fork into one's mouth but look really weird and sometimes spill food everywhere, these are the kinds of issues you get from wired reflexes.  It's not just your body, your mind is moving faster too.  *Most* runners who use them only turn them on when necessary, which works fine once their on; there isn't really much of an 'adjustment time' needed: if you've any of the latest FPS games you're probably familiar with moving in slow-mo which is basically what happens when the reflexes are on.  The main disadvantage of doing this is that you might not have time to turn them on in certain situations (e.g. an ambush) before it's already too late.  Also they make you physically better with basically no drawbacks at almost any task, which makes using them desirable, even if it's mind-numbingly boring.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time characters get equipment like wired reflexes between adventures, so its accepted that they have passed the adaptation time, but if it comes that this is part of an ongoing game you have this:

**Cybersurgery and recovery time (p.451 core rulebook)** says that you get Essence cost x3 damage boxes, both physical and stun, so you can argue that the damage and his penalty to dice pool is the penalty while the character gets used to his new cyberware, so his recovery time would be equal to the times according to the **Healing (p.205 core rulebook)** section, where you have to check if he is having a natural healing or medical assisted, the rules ask for some rolls to be done to see how well the character is recovering, so it introduces some random on the recovery time, which is good so the character can´t know in advance how much time would last his recovery.

I would say that the time for A and B cases is calculated with the same rules, only changes the essence cost, hence the time, also the **Wired reflexes** specifies that must be activated, but **Reaction enhancers** are always on **(both p.455 core rulebook)**, but times would not change, if you want some guy get **Wired Reflexes** always on the time to get used would be calculated the same way, maybe you should add some **Negative quality** to reflect that being boosted 100% of the time causes some kind of **Addiction**, **Insomnia** or **Unsteady Hands** **(p.76 core rulebook)**